# Use default options when compiling ports

Tags: freebsd-ports

I am compiling a few ports on FreeBSD, however during the compiling process I am often greeted with options for the dependencies of the port. This causes the compiling process to pause until I select (or in 9/10 cases, just leave the defaults) "OK". This is inconvenient because the compiling process is often long, I would like to walk away from the computer and not worry about having to select options.

I am wondering if there is an argument or compiler flag I can use to automatically use all defaults for dependencies of the port that I am compiling.

I tried to research this, but most likely I was not using the correct terminology in my queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option (IMHO) is to set all the options at the very start. You can do this by running `make config-recursive`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `BATCH=1` to /etc/make.conf.

Comment: or the command-line, even ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using portupgrade. I recommend using ports-mgmt/portmaster. One of the reasons is that it runs `make config` recursively before starting to compile, so the options screen won't interrupt the compiling process. And you won't have to think about running `make config-recursive`.